# Counting distinct element for each record and updating them

Tags: mysql

This my student Record table and i'm trying to find for each student, the number of other students with the same first or last name and save it in samefirst and samelast for each student.

```
   +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | first     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | last      | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | samefirst | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | samelast  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


select a.first as af, a.last as al, b.first as bf, b.last as bl  
from StudRec a inner join
     StudRec b
     on a.first = b.first and a.last <> b.last) or 
        a.first <> b.first and a.last = b.last;
```

The query above gives me each student and his matching first or last with another students but I'm having difficulties doing the count for each student and insert it into samefirst and samelast. Thanks in advace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use correlation subquery to find for each student, students with similar first name or last name.

```
SELECT SR.first,
       SR.last,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StudRec AS SR2
        WHERE SR2.first = SR.first) AS samefirst,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StudRec AS SR2
        WHERE SR2.last = SR.last) AS samelast
FROM StudRec AS SR
```

Comment: I don't know mysql syntax, the general idea is next:  

    `UPDATE StudRec
         SET samefirst = T.samefirst,
                 samelast = T.samelast
FROM StudRec AS ST
    JOIN (SELECT SR.first,
       SR.last,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StudRec AS SR2
     WHERE SR2.first = SR.first) AS samefirst,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StudRec AS SR2
     WHERE SR2.last = SR.last) AS samelast
    FROM StudRec AS SR ) AS T ON T.first = ST.first
                                     AND T.last = ST.last`

Answer (score 1):

This is complicated because you need to do an update.  In MySQL, you are not supposed to use the table being updated in subqueries.  You can get around this using `join`:

```
update studrec sr left join
       (select first, count(*) as cnt
        from studrec
        group by first
       ) f
       on sr.first = f.first left join
       (select last, count(*) as cnt
        from studrec
        group by last
       ) l
       on sr.last = l.last
    set samefirst = coalesce(f.cnt, 0),
        samelast = coalesce(l.cnt, 0);
```

Comment: it looks like the coalesce is not working I have tried ISNULL  and that also didnt work...Thanks for the timely response

Comment: I'm surprised you accepted an answer that only uses `select` because the question implies that you want to modify the actual table.